# The silent function in my .reg file not working

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, registry

I have created a batch file to execute a .reg

The syntax in my batch file is as follows:

```
# "REGEDIT.EXE /S \\\MyServer\Share\Folder\Folder\MyFile.reg"
```

I have the "/S" to disable prompting, but when I execute this batch I'm still prompted. The actual batch executes perfectly, but how can I get rid of this prompting?

Comment: The silent ones are always the worst :)

Comment: What does the prompt say?  Have you tried `reg import` instead of regedit?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know how that code can do anything, since the # and the quotes and the triple backslash make this not a valid statement, but if they weren't there, depending on your group policy or UAC level, you'd get the UAC prompt, ie. windows requires admin privileges for regedit. there is no way around that except starting from an already elevated prompt. the /s switch just suppresses regedit's confirmation question.

Comment: of course it does. can't have just anybody hacking the registry.

Comment: Try it and see!  Some enterprise admins disable regedit via group policy, but by default, anybody can run it.  There's no security issue, because (unless you run it elevated) you're only allowed to write to keys in your own user hive.